# Streaming data to the caller in JVM

Tags: clojure, stream, jvm, core.async

I have a function which gets data periodically and then stops getting the data. This function has to return the data that it is fetching periodically to the caller of the function either

1. As and when it gets
2. At one shot

The 2nd one is an easy implementation i.e you block the caller, fetch all the data and then send it in one shot. 
But I want to implement the 1st one (I want to avoid having callbacks). Is streams the things to be used here? If so, how? If not, how do I return `something` on which the caller can query for data and also stop when it returns a signal that there is no more data?

Note: I am on the JVM ecosystem, clojure to be specific. I have had a look at the clojure library `core.async` which kind of solves this kind of a problem with the use of channels. But I was thinking if there is any other way which probably looks like this (assuming streams is something that can be used). 

Java snippet

```
//Function which will periodically fetch MyData until there is no data
public Stream<MyData> myFunction() {
...
}

myFunction().filter(myData -> myData.text.equals("foo"))
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about how the calling/downstream code looks. Besides `core.async`, you could return a `future`, for example.

Comment: @AlanThompson Future of what? That is the question. `myFunction` will end up returning an `Array/Seq/List` of `MyData` but each block of `MyData` is available in a separate frame of time. For eg, returning a `Future<List<MyData>>` would not be idea because I would again end up getting the all the blocks of `MyData` as a List when the Future completes. 
Instead, I want to be able to pass on the block of `MyData` as and when it is obtained and let the caller collect all of them and process it as a list or however they want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just use `seq` - which is lazy by default (like Stream) so caller can decide when to pull the data in.  And when there are no more data  `myFunction` can simply end the sequence.  While doing this, you would also encapsulate some optimisation within `myFunction` - e.g. to get data in batch to minimise roundtrips.  Or fetch data periodically per your original requirement.

Here is one naive implementation:

```clj
(defn my-function []
  (let [batch 100]
    (->> (range)
         (map #(let [from (* batch %)
                     to   (+ from batch)]
                  (db-get from to)))
         ;; take while we have data from db-get
         (take-while identity)
         ;; returns as one single seq/Stream
         (apply concat))))

;; use it as a normal seq/Stream
(->> (my-function)
     (filter odd?))
```

where `db-get` would be something like:

```clj
(defn db-get [from to]
  ;; return first 1000 records only, i.e. returns nil to signal completion
  (when (< from 1000)
    ;; returns a range of records
    (range from to)))
```

Comment: Your answer works if I remove the line `apply concat`. With that, it waits for all the results before returning. Not sure why that happens?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava and https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxClojure (seems no longer maintained?)

Comment: Stream like solution can't be used here? I don't want to go with observables here

Comment: A channel could be a good solution but I recommended looking into Rx because it looked like a closer match, but you'll have to judge. `core.async` could be a good fit too, if you can call a function that will return a channel in which 0 or more values will be available in the future. Remember that channels are like a conveyor belt so they can't grow forever. There's a good tutorial here: https://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/